# How to export VocabularyProcessor and use it after TF serve loading?

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I have two parts of my code:

- script for training data (python+tf+bag_of_words)
- script for predict class of any string (now python, but later golang in
  production)

I am going to train my model at python and use model in production through golang API.

Training steps:

1. Fit `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor`
2. Train with BOW algorithm
3. Add output `tf.estimator.export.ClassificationOutput`
4. Add input `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver`
5. Export my `tf.estimator.Estimator` by `export_savedmodel`

It works fine, but I want proxy from my client to the model `string`. And this `string` should be converted to vector through VocabularyProcessor. But VocabularyProcessor is not tensor and I can not use it as graph node. And I can not pickle it because I will not restore it with golang client implementation.

Is it possible to resolve my question?

```
def preprocess_for_prediction(n_words):
  def serving_input_fn():
    words = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
    receiver_inputs = {"raw_words": words}

    # Now use const by needed to convert raw_words to vector
    vector = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], shape=(1, 10), dtype=tf.int32)
    features = {WORDS_FEATURE: vector}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_inputs)

  return serving_input_fn
```

UPD:

I just read about tensorflow-transform. I think it will work for me, after trying I will write answer here.